# Is it possible to run LuaTeX from a USB flash drive

Tags: windows, luatex

I am looking for ways to install and run LuaTeX on a USB flash drive (Windows operating system).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ConTeXt minimals](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Minimals) does not require any installation and  can be run from a USB stick. It contains the latest luatex binary along with plain and context macro packages ... but no latex. So, depending on what macro package you want to use, it may or may not be useful.

Answer (score 8):

LuaTeX will be included MiKTeX 2.9, due out soon. When that happens, I presume you'll be able to run it (and hence LuaTeX) on [MiKTeX Portable](http://miktex.org/portable/about). (I couldn't see anything about the portable version on the [MiKTeX 2.9 beta page](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup).)

Answer (score 8):

TeX Live also offers a portable mode, thought it's not well documented (if at all) currently. With TeX Live 2010, use `install-tl -portable`, then select your USB stick as the destination folder. You can customize the installation as usual (eg, selecting only the packages you need in order to save space). One installed, all you need to do is to run the `tl-portable.bat` script at the root of the installation.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. I did try MikTeX and it works ok, but I will also give this a try!

Answer (score 4):

[Although this question is old it may be relevant to someone.]

You may also put together your very own set of features using Akira Kakuto's W32TeX from http://w32tex.org/. It is based on TeX Live and is Windows exclusive.