# What are Portable latex facilities?

Tags: minimal, portable

I am looking for a minimalist Latex installation that can be installed on a USB key.
I also want to use this key on my workstation without interfering with my installation (MikTex).
What do you know?

Comment: On Windows see here: [https://miktex.org/howto/portable-edition](https://miktex.org/howto/portable-edition)

Comment: Apart from the above link you could also check out https://portableapps.com . There is an older MikTeX installation available, which I used before, including a portable version of TeXStudio. Portableapps helped me a lot using my favorite programs on restricted access computers in class rooms … *don’t tell anyone …*

Comment: Probably duplicate of one of [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75407)
[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267986)
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81802)
[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3751)
[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410192)

. Although I haven't gone through them to see if they're applicable.

Comment: Actually my question is mostly about a minimalist version of latex.
I will review both proposals.
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this description of making the TeXLive portable: https://tug.org/texlive/archive/portable-anchor.html

They propose:

> Running from USB
>
> You can run the normal TeX Live installation and make the output
> directory be a USB stick. Then you do several things:
>
> Use the tl-portable script to run completely from the stick, without
> touching the host system at all. As described in the documentation,
> tl-portable starts a new shell (command prompt) within which you do
> your work.

On the page https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-420004.2 we can read

> 4.2 Portable (USB) installations
>
> The -portable installer option (or V command in the text installer or
> corresponding GUI option) creates a completely self-contained TeX Live
> installation under a common root and forgoes system integration. You
> can create such an installation directly on a USB stick, or copy it to
> a USB stick afterwards.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).